# Specify page/line when throwing die()?

Tags: php, die

I am using PHP 4, the only way I know of to cause an error and stop everything is calling die(). But in case I run into the error later and don't remember where its coming from I would like to specify the page and line number that the die() occurred on (like other php errors do). Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not relevant to your question at all but please consider not using PHP4. It has reached its "end of life" so won't receive any more official patches or fixes.

Comment: I agree with @Oli - it's time to upgrade!

Comment: @oli thanks I plan to upgrade when I upgrade servers with my host.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look into the [magic constants.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

```
echo __LINE__; // Line number
```

You can also run [error_log()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) to send errors quietly to the log.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use:

```
echo __FILE__ . ": line " . __LINE__;
die();
```

If you were to use PHP5, you could also use Exceptions:

```
throw new Exception("My error message!");
```

The stack trace will reveal the whole call stack and the line this was thrown on.

(EDIT: Thanks to [@John Isaacs] and [@Emil H] for informing me that Exceptions weren't added to PHP until PHP5)

Comment: I believe Exceptions were added in v5.

Comment: Correct, Exceptions isn't available before v5.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I tried to do a cursory lookup to see when exceptions were added, but could not spot it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use [trigger_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) to generate an E_USER_ERROR or E_USER_WARNING. This allows you to control the behaviour in detail. For example you can specify whether the messages should be shown at all using [error_reporting()](https://www.php.net/error_reporting), or handle the E_USER_WARNING:s explicitly using set_error_handler().

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Jukka Dahlbom and @Ólafur Waage's suggestions you might also consider using [`debug_backtrace()`](http://www.php.net/debug_backtrace).

Comment: Very unfortunately, a `die`-triggered shutdown handler won't have the `die` in the backtrace. D:

Answer (score 0):

Better use [`error_log()`](http://docs.php.net/error_log) to report an error and [`debug_backtrace()`](http://docs.php.net/debug_backtrace) for debugging. You could also write your own error handling function (see [`set_error_handler()`](http://docs.php.net/set_error_handler)) to combine both.